# How to get printer where report was printed

Tags: printing, visual-foxpro, foxpro

If PROMPT calsue is used in report

```
REPORT FORM xxx to PRINT PROMPT
```

User can select printer where report is printed.
How to get this printer name for logging?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/162798/how-to-use-the-set-printer-to-name-command-to-print-to-a-specified-printer-in-visual-foxpro

Show hot to use GetPrinter() for this. This requires removing PROMPT clause from REPORT

How to get printer where report was printed using PROMPT clause:
REPORT FORM xxx TO PRINT PROMPT

If this possbible, maybe thereis some sys() function or somethis other or is it possible to get printer name during report print ?

Or should this command re-factored not to use PROMPT clause like:

```
cPrinter = getprinter()
set printer to name (cPrinter)
REPORT FORM xxx TO PRINT
insert into logfile (PrinterUsedForPrinting) values (cPrinter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using your solution of calling GETPRINTER prior to running the report (without the PROMPT clause). In my long experience using FoxPro/VFP I don't think I've come across a way to determine the printer via  REPORT FORM...PROMPT.

Here's an example wrapper function that you may find useful. I typically call "PickPrinter" prior to running a report. If PickPrinter returns an empty string, I abort the report run.

```
FUNCTION PickPrinter
    IF APRINTERS(a_printers) < 1
        MESSAGEBOX("No printers defined.")
        RETURN ""
    ELSE
        lcPrnChoice = ""
        lcPrnChoice = GETPRINTER()
        IF EMPTY(lcPrnChoice)
            RETURN ""
        ELSE
            *** Include quotes around the printer name
            *** in case there are spaces in the name
            lcPrnChoice = "NAME [" + lcPrnChoice + "]"
            SET PRINTER TO &lcPrnChoice

            RETURN lcPrnChoice
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
ENDFUNC
```